# Find a function that is a bijection $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (1, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Find a function that is a bijection $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (1, \infty)$

I am to assume the intervals have the same cardinality.  I honestly don't even know how to begin with this.  Can you provide me with hints on how to get started?

Comment: Can you name a function that will send, say, 0 to positive infinity (in the limit, naturally) and 1 to 1 in such a way that the function is one-to-one and has an inverse?

Comment: There is even a  bijection that is continuous in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: Even just $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ $ on $ \ (0, \ 1) \ $  would suffice, wouldn't it?  Nothing says the ordering of elements must be preserved.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner There is some appeal in preserving as much as possible... but it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks!  After graphing this function I understand why it works, but how did you even begin to come up with this?  Did you just think about functions that send $1$ off into infinity?

Comment: @free_mind, yes, I sent $1$ to $ \infty$. It turned out nicely that $0$ goes to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Idea:** think about $\tan$, on $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Now rescale to get from $(0,1)$ to $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ first.

Comment: Or $ \ \sec \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x \right) \  $ , which won't need a horizontal translation.

Comment: Yes, but $\tan$ came to mind immediately, and I did not want to wait a $\sec$.